# How do i get variables from a html form using a session wrapper class in PHP?

Tags: php, session

Ok  i have a session class that currently handles setting variables, getting variables, deleting them and destroying them. I have a form which take information from a user and i am not sure how i would get the post variables using a session class rather than just using $_SESSION{'some variable'] to set the variables and use them.

```
<?php

class sessionClass{

public function _constructor()
{
  session_start();
}


public function destroy()
{
 session_destroy();
}

public function add($name, $value)
{
   if(empty($name)){
   die('Invalid variable name');
   }
   $_SESSION[$name] = $value;


}


public function delete($name)
{
  session_unset ($_SESSION[$name]);
}


public function get($name)
{
if(isset($_SESSION[$name]))
    $_SESSION[$name] = $name;
else
  return ($_SESSION[$name]);
}


}




?>
```

Above is my session class. Now i am trying to use OOPHP and i am trying to validate the data being entered into my template form page. However because i am passing the variables $_POST['LoginID'] and $_POST['Password'] i am getting these errors.

Notice: Undefined index: LoginID in /home/comp3170-020/public_html/assignment2/index.php on line 20 Notice: Undefined index: LoginID in /home/comp3170-020/public_html/assignment2/index.php on line 25   ect ect

```
//Creating class objects
$val = new validatorClass();
$ses = new sessionClass();
$dis = new XHTMLDisplayClass();

$dis->setTemplate('templates/index.tpl.php');

//Checking that data is validated
if (isset($_POST['Submit']))
{

        if ((!$val->isValidLoginID($_POST['LoginID'])) || (!$val->isValidLoginIDE($_POST['LoginID'])) ||(!isValidPassword($_POST['Password'])))
        {
            $errs = $val->getErrorMessages();
            $d-> addVar('errors', $errs);   
        }

         else {
            //$ses = new sessionClass();
              $ses->add('LoginID', $_POST['LoginID']);
              $ses->add('Password',$_POST['Password'] );
              $ses->add('validationDone', true);
              header('Location:auth.php');
            exit;
            }
    }
```

Can anyone tell me how i should pass the variables to the functions of the classes.

form code :

```
<form name="form1" action="index.php"  method="POST">
                <td width="220" class="content_l">Login ID</td>
                <font color = "FF0000">
                <?php if (isset ($errors['isValidLoginID'])){echo $errors['isValidLoginID'];}?>
              <?php if (isset ($errors['isValidLoginIDE'])){echo $errors['isValidLoginIDE'];}?>
              <?php if (isset ($errors['isValidPassword'])){echo $errors['isValidPassword'];}?>
              </font>
              </tr>

              <tr>
                <td><input type="text" name="textfield" class="form250"></td>
              </tr>

              <tr>
                <td height="25" valign="bottom" class="content_l">Password</td>
                </tr>

              <tr>
                <td><input type="password" name="textfield" class="form250" ></td>
                </tr>

              <tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td height="25" valign="bottom" class="content_1">Identification Used</td>
                  </tr>

                  <tr>
                    <td><input type="radio" name="authtyp" value="Username" class="form250" <?php echo $usertyp?> checked>Username &nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="radio" name="authtyp" value= "Email" class="form250" <?php echo $emailtyp?>> Email</td>
                  </tr>

                  <tr> 
                    <td height="40" valign="bottom">
                        <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="LOGIN" class="btn70" style="margin-top:10px; "> 
                 </form> 
                  </td>
              </tr>

              <tr>
                <td height="30" valign="bottom"><a href="#" class="content_m" style="color:#333333">Forgot your password? </a></td>
                </tr>
            </table></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
          </tr>
          </table>
```

Comment: how are you setting the `$_POST` variable? are you using a html form? you need to share the relevant html markup as well

Comment: ok i added the form code

Comment: `<input type="text" name="textfield" class="form250">` should be `<input type="text" name="LOGINID" class="form250">` and `<input type="password" name="textfield" class="form250" >` should be `<input type="password" name="Password" class="form250" >`. the name attribute is what is used as the key in `$_POST` array. you haven't set the names of the inputs in your form which you are trying to access in your php code. hence you are getting the `notice`

Comment: ok thanks for pointing that out, didnt realise that. However the error is still there.

Comment: i need to point out that in the earlier comment it should `LoginID` and not `LOGINID`. apologies

Comment: are you getting the notice for both `LoginID` and `Password`?